# How to slow down internet connection?

Tags: networking, wireless, bandwidth, download-speed

I have a very large download to perform which is low priority.

Can I throttle back the networking speed of my **Ubuntu 18.10** so this download does not bog down my connection which is shared with other computers?

I am on a home wifi connection.

I can use a browser to perform this download or wget, etc... yet do not see such a setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` has `--limit-rate` option for limiting the download speed; from `man wget`:

> --limit-rate=amount
>
> Limit the download speed to amount bytes per second.  Amount may be expressed in bytes, kilobytes with the k suffix, or megabytes with
>   the m suffix.  For example, --limit-rate=20k will limit the retrieval
>   rate to 20KB/s.  This is useful when, for whatever reason, you don't
>   want Wget to consume the entire available bandwidth.
>
> This option allows the use of decimal numbers, usually in conjunction with power suffixes; for example, --limit-rate=2.5k is a
>   legal value.
>
> Note that Wget implements the limiting by sleeping the appropriate amount of time after a network read that took less time than specified
>   by the rate.  Eventually this strategy causes the TCP transfer to slow
>   down to approximately the specified rate.  However, it may take some
>   time for this balance to be achieved, so don't be surprised if
>   limiting the rate doesn't work well with very small files.

FWIW, `curl` also has a similar `--limit-rate` option for controlling both upload and download speeds. Check `man curl`.